# How to calculate translate x and y value when resize after rotate..?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, resize

I am working with HTML div element **corner based resize in javascript**.

#### Below image shows rotate resize operation:

[image]

**Corner based resize** working perfect when selection box div is unrotated (i.e. `rotate(0 deg)`).

After rotate, i am using **bottom-right corner as handle** to resize the selection box div, when **top-left corner** needs to remain in same position.

As like having **four handles**, with opposite corner needs to remain in same position when resize.

But the problem is, the selection box top-left **corner not remains in same position**.

I need to **calculate translate x and y** value for corner based resize after rotate.

#### Known values:

`scale`, `center_x`, `center_y`, `previous_x`, `previous_y`, `width`, `height`, `previous_width`, `previous_height`, `diff_width`, `diff_height`, `radian_angle`, `rotated_degree`.

#### HTML code (`selection box div`):

```
<div class="box" style="transform: translate(132px, 190px) rotate(0deg); width: 295px; height: 234px;">
<div>
```

#### Sample code used to resize after rotate:

```
switch (handle) {
  case 'bottom-right':
    x = previous_x - ? ;        //logic behind after rotated some angles..?
    y = previous_y + ? ;
    break;
  case 'bottom-left':
    x = ? ;
    y = ? ;
    break;
  case 'top-left':
    x = ? ;
    y = ? ;
    break;
  case 'top-right':
    x = ? ;
    y = ? ;
    break;
  default:
}
```

#### Below corner based resize code works perfect when resize with unrotated div (`rotate(0 deg)`):

```
case 'bottom-right':
  x = previous_x;
  y = previous_y;
  break;
case 'bottom-left':
  x = previous_x - diff_width;
  y = previous_y;
  break;
```

How to calculate translate x & y value after rotate to get fixed corner when resize.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help. But I think you can reach it with Trigonometry (cosinus, sinus and your rotation angle) because your rotation draw a circle.