# How to maintain fixed corner while resize a DIV element after rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, resize

Working in HTML div to **rotate and resize with Javascript**.

**Sample image:**
[image]

I can't able to make a **corner remains fixed** while resize after rotate.

Possible duplicates are:

[How to calculate translate x and y value when resize after rotate..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827557/how-to-calculate-translate-x-and-y-value-when-resize-after-rotate)

[Resize logic to maintain a fixed corner after rotate in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851386/resize-logic-to-maintain-a-fixed-corner-after-rotate-in-javascript)

[How to resize with fixed corner after rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931697/how-to-resize-with-fixed-corner-after-rotate)

No use for me from the above link.

I need a similar functionality like [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/fXT0kZcRwJTPb7wQVHpg/) one, but its svg. I need **this with div elements**, not for svg.

I checked too more links like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86755/how-to-calculate-corner-positions-marks-of-a-rotated-tilted-rectangle/86784) one, those are only used to find corner positions after rotate, but **after finding this how to set corner fixed while resize..?**

What is the step by step procedure to maintain opposite corners fixed when resize after rotate..?

I used one [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/v8qoLj76/34/) for reference to understand by need, but i achieved center based resize after rotate, i can't add all the codes. I can resize with corner fixed with `0 deg` and `360 deg`, but i need fixed corner with all others angles.

**Note:** To maintain fixed corner after rotate [Canva](https://www.canva.com) and [Powtoon](https://www.powtoon.com/account/login/) made some adjustments in `translate(x,y)` => by Canva and `left`,`top` => by Powtoon.

Comment: I tried all rotate properties, but i need to achieve corner based resize. I also tried `transform-origin`, i made some changes in position while resize. Can you same me the procedure or logic to get translate x and y values as like used by [Canva](https://www.canva.com) and [Powtoon](https://www.powtoon.com/account/login/)

Comment: I mentioned that i need to rotate image from center, and resize from corner. And that link is http://embed.plnkr.co/fXT0kZcRwJTPb7wQVHpg/ only the reference like i need in HTML div. I don't need that in SVG.

Comment: Can you say me the logic like subtract the scale with angle from the current x value.. Like that logic only i need.. If you gave any samples code also useful for me. But those links given by me are only reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157863/discussion-between-arunvalaven-and-philicare).

Comment: can't you use this css's in your javascript code?: https://jsfiddle.net/nnymd7md/

Comment: You can look at my answer, @ArunValaven

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez .. I can able to add `transform-origin` css code through javascript. But its making some deviation in that div element while click corner or while starting to rotate.

Comment: OMG... No one here to help me..?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a start? (not the 100% solution, but a way to approach it, improvable):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  /** 
    * The rotation method
    *
    * @param domElement  The element to rotate
    * @param origin      The origin of the rotate
    * @param degree      The degrees amount for the angle
    */
  function rotate(domElement, origin, degree) {
      $(domElement)
        .css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'})
        .css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'})
        .css({'transform-origin': origin || 'bottom right'})
        ;                   
      // To avoid to 'too much' recursion, we use a timeout
      let timer = setTimeout(function() {
        rotate(++degree);
        clearTimeout(timer);
      },5);
  }
  
  let Cadre       = $('div#cadre')
    , curHandler  = undefined
    , startPosX   = 0
    , startPosY   = 0
    ;
  
  /**
    * When user click down on a handler
    * => curHandler is defined => we work
    */
  $('.handler').mousedown(function(ev){
    startPosX = ev.pageX ;
    startPosY = ev.pageY ;
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    curHandler = $(this);
  })
  /**
    * When user click up on a handler
    * => curHandler is undefined => stop work
    */
  $('.handler').mouseup(function(ev){
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    curHandler = undefined ;
  })
  
  /**
    * When user move the mouse
    * We only work when an handler (curHandler) is defined
    * Otherwise, we do nothing
    */
  $('body').mousemove(function(ev){
    if (curHandler)
    {
      // <= A handler is defined (click down)
      // => we rotate when mouse mouve
      angle = startPosX - ev.pageX ;
      // The rotation origin is set in the HTML Handler, but
      // we could get it from a JS constant or anything
      rotate(Cadre, curHandler.attr('data-origin'), angle);     }
  })
})
```

```css
div#cadre { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    clear:both;
  }
  div.handler {position:absolute; width:5%;height:10px;background-color:red;}
  div.handler.clicked{background-color:green!important;}
  div.tl-handler {top:0; left:0;}
  div.tr-handler {top:0; right:0;}
  div.bl-handler {bottom:0; left:0;}
  div.br-handler {bottom:0; right:0;}
  div.mt-handler {top:0;left:47.5%;}
  div.mb-handler {bottom:0;left:47.5%;}
  
  div#explain {font-size:9.2pt;font-style:italic;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="explain">Click on the green handler to stop rotation (if any)</div>
<div id="cadre">
  <div class="handler tl-handler" data-origin="top left"></div>
  <div class="handler tr-handler" data-origin="top right"></div>
  <div class="handler bl-handler" data-origin="bottom left"></div>
  <div class="handler br-handler" data-origin="bottom right"></div>
  <div class="handler mt-handler" data-origin="50% top"></div>
  <div class="handler mb-handler" data-origin="50% bottom"></div>
</div>
```

### RESIZE

After that, you can play with `<jQuerySet>.css({:width, :height})` to change the width and the height when mouse moves keeping the box angle.

Comment: Can you please do for the resize after rotate..?

Comment: I need rotate from center and resize from corner. If i click and drag bottom-left as handle, need to fix top-left corner as fixed while resize after rotate. Can you do that..?

Comment: Yes i need opposite corner to be fixed while resizing after rotate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157873/discussion-between-arunvalaven-and-philicare).

Comment: OMG... No one here to help me..?