# Logic to set fixed corner while resize after rotate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, resize

**Possible duplicates are:**

[How to calculate translate x and y value when resize after rotate..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827557/how-to-calculate-translate-x-and-y-value-when-resize-after-rotate)

[Resize logic to maintain a fixed corner after rotate in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851386/resize-logic-to-maintain-a-fixed-corner-after-rotate-in-javascript)

[How to resize with fixed corner after rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931697/how-to-resize-with-fixed-corner-after-rotate)

[How to maintain fixed corner while resize a DIV element after rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030024/how-to-maintain-fixed-corner-while-resize-a-div-element-after-rotate)

Working in **resize and rotate functionality with javascript.**

**Reference diagram:** Rotated `40 deg`
[image]

The above diagram shows the **corner A need to set fixed** while **resize(using corner C)** after rotated to some degrees.

Checked links like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86755/how-to-calculate-corner-positions-marks-of-a-rotated-tilted-rectangle/86784), after finding corners position, how to maintain corner fixed..?

Code in [JS fiddle..!](http://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/5cfsqmqj/)

**Note:** To maintain fixed corner after rotate [Canva](https://www.canva.com) and [Powtoon](https://www.powtoon.com/account/login/) made some adjustments in `translate(x,y)` => by Canva and `left`,`top` => by Powtoon.

Comment: Add some x/y lines to your image, then you've got some triangles you can do cool *sin,cos,tan* math with....

Comment: Please give some reference code or link..

Comment: Nope. Im giving tips only ;)

Comment: Even i don't know how to google this to add x y lines to image to get triangle.. Anyway ok..

Comment: Have you visited Canva and Powtoon..? Is it your tips related to that websites or your own tips..?

Comment: It's not really a solution, but I guess you could temporarily rotate back, resize and then rotate again?

Comment: @SimonW .. Ya.. its not really a solution.... can you help me how to fix that corner remains in same position..?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem in the code. Did you find a solution?