# how to resize div after rotating it (is it possible to modify the mouse event coordinates based on the rotation?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

there are 8 nodes around a div which can resize the div in 8 directions, when the div is not rotated, they can resize properly. However, when the div is rotated, for example, 90 degrees clockwise, then the behavior is weird, since the mouse event is different with the rotated div.

i've checked these but didn't help:

- [Logic to set fixed corner while resize after rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089640/logic-to-set-fixed-corner-while-resize-after-rotate)
- [How to resize with fixed corner after rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931697/how-to-resize-with-fixed-corner-after-rotate)

i made a demo here: https://output.jsbin.com/nobasavaza

any ideas?

```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <title></title>
      <style>
        #cut {
          opacity: 0.6;
          height: 150px;
          width: 150px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 150px;
          left: 150px;
          cursor: pointer;
          border: 1px dotted red;
    
        }
    
        .box-resize {
          border: 1px solid black;
          width: 4px;
          height: 4px;
          position: absolute;
        }
    
        .box-top-left {
          top: -3px;
          left: -3px;
          cursor: nw-resize;
        }
    
        .box-top-right {
          top: -3px;
          right: -3px;
          cursor: ne-resize;
        }
    
        .box-left-center {
          top: 50%;
          left: -3px;
          cursor: w-resize;
        }
    
        .box-right-center {
          top: 50%;
          right: -3px;
          cursor: e-resize;
        }
    
        .box-bottom-left {
          left: -3px;
          bottom: -3px;
          cursor: sw-resize;
        }
    
        .box-bottom-right {
          right: -3px;
          bottom: -3px;
          cursor: se-resize;
        }
    
        .box-top-center {
          left: 50%;
          top: -3px;
          cursor: n-resize;
        }
    
        .box-bottom-center {
          left: 50%;
          bottom: -3px;
          cursor: s-resize;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="rotate_degree" placeholder="degree in closewise">
      <button id="rotate_submit">rorate</button>
      <div id="cut">
        hello
        <div class="box-resize box-top-left"></div>
        <div class="box-resize box-top-right"></div>
        <div class="box-resize box-left-center"></div>
        <div class="box-resize box-right-center"></div>
        <div class="box-resize box-bottom-left"></div>
        <div class="box-resize box-bottom-right"></div>
        <div class="box-resize box-top-center"></div>
        <div class="box-resize box-bottom-center"></div>
      </div>
      <script> 
        window.onload = function () {
          var resize = document.getElementsByClassName("box-resize");
          var cut = document.getElementById("cut");
          var cutWidth = 0;
          var cutHeight = 0;
          var startX = 0;
          var startY = 0;
          var top = 0;
          var left = 0;
          var dir = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < resize.length; i++) {
            resize[i].onmousedown = function (e) {
              startX = e.clientX;
              startY = e.clientY;
              cutWidth = cut.offsetWidth;
              cutHeight = cut.offsetHeight;
              top = cut.offsetTop;
              left = cut.offsetLeft;
              var className = this.className;
              if (className.indexOf("box-right-center") > -1) {
                dir = "E";
              }
              else if (className.indexOf("box-top-left") > -1) {
                dir = "NW";
              }
              else if (className.indexOf("box-top-right") > -1) {
                dir = "NE";
              }
              else if (className.indexOf("box-left-center") > -1) {
                dir = "W";
              }
              else if (className.indexOf("box-bottom-left") > -1) {
                dir = "SW";
              }
              else if (className.indexOf("box-bottom-right") > -1) {
                dir = "SE";
              }
              else if (className.indexOf("box-bottom-center") > -1) {
                dir = "S";
              }
              else if (className.indexOf("box-top-center") > -1) {
                dir = "N";
              }
              document.addEventListener('mousemove', test);
    
              e.preventDefault();
    
            }
          }
    
    
          document.onmouseup = function (e) {
            dir = "";
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', test);
    
            e.preventDefault();
    
          }
    
          function test(e) {
            var width = e.clientX - startX;
            var height = e.clientY - startY;
    
            if (dir == "E") {
              cut.style.width = cutWidth + width + "px";
            }
            else if (dir == "S") {
              cut.style.height = cutHeight + height + "px";
            }
            else if (dir == "N") {
              if (height < cutHeight) {
                cut.style.height = cutHeight - height + "px";
                cut.style.top = top + height + "px";
              }
            }
            else if (dir == "W") {
              if (width < cutWidth) {
                cut.style.width = cutWidth - width + "px";
                cut.style.left = left + width + "px";
              }
            }
            else if (dir == "NW") {
              if (width < cutWidth && height < cutHeight) {
                cut.style.width = cutWidth - width + "px";
                cut.style.height = cutHeight - height + "px";
                cut.style.top = top + height + "px";
                cut.style.left = left + width + "px";
              }
            }
            else if (dir == "NE") {
              if (height < cutHeight) {
                cut.style.width = cutWidth + width + "px";
                cut.style.height = cutHeight - height + "px";
                cut.style.top = top + height + "px";
              }
            }
            else if (dir == "SW") {
              if (width < cutWidth) {
                cut.style.width = cutWidth - width + "px";
                cut.style.height = cutHeight + height + "px";
                cut.style.left = left + width + "px";
              }
            }
            else if (dir == "SE") {
              if (width < cutWidth) {
                cut.style.width = cutWidth + width + "px";
                cut.style.height = cutHeight + height + "px";
              }
            }
          }
        }
    
    
        document.getElementById('rotate_submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
          const degree = document.getElementById('rotate_degree');
          document.getElementById("cut").style.transform = 'rotate(' + degree.value + 'deg)';
        })
    
      </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

```

Comment: There's probably some way of moving the transform to a parent container of the cut element and then use it's transformed coordinate system for your clientX and Y. If you were using an svg, it would probably not take much to get it working. You could transform the entire svg, which would alter its viewbox so your mousemove coordinates always reflect what you'd expect after rotating.

Comment: I will make an example for you if I get some time today.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jb1w0yeg/

Made it resize box according to correct square, but issue now is the offset values. It is still treating the "top" of the cut element as the upper-left corner, no matter how much transform you apply to it. It was an interesting attempt, but I don't know off the top of my head how to overcome that. If you did it with pure svg elements, using a rect inside the svg instead of a div, you could manipulate the rect by its x, y, height and width attributes and never have to mess with offsets. That would make it very simple, and much of your logic would already apply.

Comment: Sorry I cannot implement that for you atm, I have to get back to work.